# Trouble creating a torrent with Transmission-create on the command line

Tags: command-line, bittorrent, transmission

Having a look at the Doc's which can be [found here.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/TransmissionHowTo#Transmission_Create)

I've attempted to recreate there exact example although I keep running into this error.

```
sudo transmission-create -o ~/home/files.torrent -c "My comments" -t udp://tracker.openbittorrent.com:80 ~/home/testfile.txt
```

Although I keep running into this error.

```
Creating torrent "/home/torrent/home/files.torrent" ...[2015-06-08 19:27:17.554 EDT] Torrent Creator is skipping file "/home/torrent": No such file or directory
. error reading "": No such file or directory
```

The only file within /home is the `testfile.txt` I've no idea where it is getting the `/home/torrent` from.

What am I missing? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error clearly says that

```
Creating torrent "/home/torrent/home/files.torrent" ...[2015-06-08 19:27:17.554 EDT] Torrent Creator is skipping file "/home/torrent": No such file or directory
. error reading "": No such file or directory
```

which from here i guess the problem is with the directory which you are pointing doesn't exit try using

```
sudo transmission-create -o ~/files.torrent -c "My comments" -t udp://tracker.openbittorrent.com:80 ~/testfile.txt
```

as ~ denotes your home directory

Comment: Ah I feel like an idiot. Basically what was wrong was I was attempting to create a torrent of an empty text file. Hence the error reading "".

I'm going to mark yours as correct as well due to the better denotation of the home directory.

Thank you.